# Is it safe to use at runtime a v90 COM dll in a v110 executable?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Is it safe to use a COM dll built with the v90 compiler in an executable built with the v110 compiler?

The v90 dll is used by the executable at run time through the COM interface (it is not `#import`ed).

The executable builds against the tlb of the dll.
Both link to MFC statically, and both use the `/MT` version of the runtime library.

My understanding is that is possible, but not safe. As there are cavets about use (i.e. memory allocation differs, so objects cannot be allocated in the dll and deleted in the executable, as this will cause unexpected behaviour).

Please can someone clarify for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is safe. Provided you obey the COM rules.

COM rules are ABI<sup>1</sup> rules that include rules relating to memory management, threads, etc.

**Do not try to subvert those rules, ever**.

Even if the same compiler is used for the dll and the exe. E.g. do not allocate with `new` on one side and `delete` on the other - even if you use the same compiler.

COM does not limit or enforce a particular language or platform on either side - there are many technologies, languages and platforms that offer COM interoperability, e.g. a COM object implemented in .Net will work with a C++ exe that imports the object, so long as both side obey the rules.

---

<sup>1</sup> Application binary interface

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very helpful. So essentially the COM interface allows differing languages and compilers to work happily together, as long as they don't break the ABI rules. Do you have a link to all ABI rules?

Comment: (ABI = Application binary interface)

Comment: Yes, I'll add that in as well.